# How to update any specific MKAnnotationView image on click button from NavigationBar?

Tags: swift3, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have added some annotationViews at Map with init method (initialised by there id). Now I want to update specific id annotation view on click button from navigation bar.

Suppose I have added 5 annotation with ids (1, 2, 3, 4, and 5)

Added from VC:

```
let annotation = MapPinAnnotation(title: storeItem.name!, location: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(lat), Double(long)), id: storeItem.storeId!)
self.mapview.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Initialised AnnotationView:

```
class MapPinAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var title:String?
    var id:String?
    private(set) var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

    init(title newTitle: String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, id: String) {
        super.init()

        self.title = newTitle
        self.coordinate = location
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

ViewFor annotation method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
            return nil
        }
        if (annotation is MapPinAnnotation) {
            let pinLocation = annotation as? MapPinAnnotation
            // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
            var annotationView: MKAnnotationView? = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "MapPinAnnotationView")
            if annotationView == nil {
                annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: Constants.Assets.PinGreen)
            }
            else {
                annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            }
            return annotationView
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Now I want to change image of annotation view(id 4) on click button from navigation bar.

How can I update? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get specific MKAnnotationView with `view(for: )` method. Try the following code:

```
func clickButton() {
    for annotation in self.mapView.annotations {
        if annotation.id == 4 {
            let annotationView = self.mapView.view(for: annotation)
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Image name here")
        }
    }
}
```